# css nav for angular-ui-bootstrap color change not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to change the background color of my active link to orange in the header. I am using bootstrap and not sure how would I do that. I trield using

```
 ul.nav a:active { 
        color: orange !important; 
    }
```

but that didnt work... any idea? below is my code

```
<style>
    div.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top{
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        border-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

</style>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My-H</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just adjust the relevant color variable in `variables.less` and recompile Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have  `<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>`,your active link (`<a>` tag) is placed in a `<li>` tag with `active` class.so try using this css instead :

```
ul.nav li.active a { 
    color: orange !important; 
}
```